# Django ORM GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: django, orm

Some trable with GROP BY and SUM
Django ORM make this query :

```
"SELECT "p_record"."h", SUM("p_record"."size") AS "size__sum" FROM "p_record" GROUP BY "p_record"."h", "p_record"."size" ORDER BY "p_record"."size" DESC LIMIT 15"
```

when I do

```
record.objects.all().values('h').annotate(Sum('size')).order_by('-size')[:15]
```

or

```
record.objects.all().values('h').order_by('h').annotate(Sum('size')).order_by('-size')[:15]
```

BUT 'h' not grouped! Where I missed bug?
tested on sqlite and postgres. Django 10.6

have some result:

```html
.
      h:         size:
  <li>"aa.ss.aa" = 15</li>
  <li>"aa.dd.aa" = 2</li>
  <li>"aa.ss.aa" = 4</li>
  <li>"zz.aa.cc" = 9</li>
  <li>"aa.ss.aa" = 9</li>
```

Comment: From the docs: Any fields used in an order_by() call are included in the SQL SELECT columns.

Comment: so what I can do for group only 'h'?

Comment: remove `size` from `order_by`

Comment: but how sort by size all summed?

Comment: Give a name to the aggregate: `annotate(size=Sum('size')).order_by('size')`

Comment: Also a bit of clarification: the cite above is about `distinct`.  But a little further the docs say: *Similarly, if you use a values() query to restrict the columns selected, the columns used in any order_by() (or
default model ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the results.*

Comment: wolfrevokcats omg, this is the last thing I have not tried! Thnx it`s work now.

Answer (score 0):

It`s work

```
record.objects.all().values('h').annotate(sumsize=Sum('size')).order_by('-sumsize')[:15]
```

summed by 'h' and sorted by Sum size